# Strange problem when running system tests as a whole with RSpec and Capybara/Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I've regular RSpec Rails system tests using Capybara/Selenium, like this:

```
RSpec.describe "Model", type: :system do
  context "update model info1" do
    # ...
  end

  context "update model info2" do
    # ...
  end

  context "update model info3" do
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

If I run these tests individually (e.g. context "update model info1" or context "update model info2") then each of them passes with success.

However, if I run them as a whole from the "root" level (i.e. from RSpec.describe "Model") then some of them fails.

Tests always run sequentially.

What is the problem? How can I make tests to pass with success even when they run as a whole?

---

If it can be useful, I'm running tests on MacOs Ventura 13.0 with rails 7.0.4.3, rspec-rails 6.0.1, capybara 3.38.0, and selenium-webdriver 4.8.1.

Comment: Are the tests doing something to disrupt the state of the other tests? Are you using the same data in different tests where it may be modified by another test causing failures? It's hard to say with more specifics.

Comment: No, no disruption of the state of the other tests. Normally, one would expect it to work as independent tests.

Comment: That's the problem... it really depends on how they are written. Just about any test can be written in such a way that they can run one at a time. The problem comes when they are run in parallel... if they aren't written "correctly", they may interfere with each other in some way but we can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: How can I check if tests run in parallel? I think they do not because one browser is used (automated with Capybara/Selenium). It would be hard to show you the code. If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your description. You said when run individually vs all together... I took all together as in parallel. If they are running in parallel, you should see multiple browsers launched and running tests at the same time, e.g. 3 tests should launch 3 browsers. If you just see one browser up and it runs test 1, then test2, then test 3, etc. then they are running sequentially. Are all tests run in the same browser? e.g. Is one browser launched and then in that browser all tests are run without the browser closing and reopening?

Comment: Yes, all the tests run in the same browser. There is a fast "visual switching" between each test start.

Comment: That might be the problem. Can you set it up so that each test: 1. start a fresh browser, 2. runs the test, 3. quits the browser? That's the ideal set up for UI tests. It ensures you get a fresh browser for each test. That still won't protect your tests from data issues, etc. but it's a start.

Comment: How can I setup the test to start and quit the browser per run?

Comment: No idea. I've never used Capybara, etc. You'll have to look through their documentation and do some googling.

Comment: I've also to say that the success/fail of tests (when run as a whole) seems to be random: sometime they pass some time they don't. ‍♂️ Maybe there is something related to session. For sure they pass when they run individually.

Comment: Or, maybe, problems occur because of the tested javascript widgets that require a transition/loading time e.g. to be displayed. So, for individual expectations, I'll experiment with the `:wait` time argument-option that can be passed to many Capybara methods (in addition to the `default_max_wait_time` global setting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems occur because the tested CSS-JS widgets have animations and transitions, which require time... and because my tests do not wait for that time.

The fix is to set the [Capybara.disable_animation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/3.6.0/Capybara/SessionConfig#disable_animation-instance_method) option to true:

```
Capybara.disable_animation = true
```

See also [this](https://scottbartell.com/2020/07/06/capybara-tip-disable-animations/).